# Failed to start the container when testing the shinyproxy-demo

Tags: docker, firewall, shinyproxy

I'm new to shinyproxy so I'm going to start learning from the wizard https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/

I followed every instruction in it all, I managed to access `localhost:8080` however, I can't get to the app, like this.

[image]

But I went ahead and followed the wizard and built the `shinyproxy-template` image, run `docker run -it -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-template`, which worked well, and then I manually added the `applicaiton.yml` file , and the same problem occurs when working with shinyproxy.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find the same situation as mine in google or stackoverflow, so I'm asking you guys for help!

My OS is `win10LTSC2021`, I installed `Docker Desktop` using `WSL2 instead of Hyper-V`

I added the `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` file manually, with the content `{ "hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"] }`

**DETAILS**

```
2024-01-04 23:20:54.736  INFO 5144 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] e.o.containerproxy.service.UserService   : User logged in [user: jack]
2024-01-04 23:20:58.153  INFO 5144 --- [pool-1-thread-1] e.o.containerproxy.service.ProxyService  : [user=jack proxyId=fe994ae3-6984-4cb7-af8d-99184149ce67 specId=01_hello] Starting proxy
2024-01-04 23:21:00.319  WARN 5144 --- [pool-1-thread-1] e.o.containerproxy.service.ProxyService  : [user=jack proxyId=fe994ae3-6984-4cb7-af8d-99184149ce67 specId=01_hello] Proxy failed to start

eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.ProxyFailedToStartException: Container with index 0 failed to start
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.AbstractContainerBackend.startProxy(AbstractContainerBackend.java:116) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.startOrResumeProxy(ProxyService.java:455) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.lambda$startProxy$4(ProxyService.java:279) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.service.ProxyService.lambda$action$11(ProxyService.java:599) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.ContainerFailedToStartException: Docker container failed to start
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.docker.DockerEngineBackend.startContainer(DockerEngineBackend.java:153) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.AbstractContainerBackend.startProxy(AbstractContainerBackend.java:108) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate(DefaultDockerClient.java:2848) ~[docker-client-8.16.0.jar!/:8.16.0]
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2712) ~[docker-client-8.16.0.jar!/:8.16.0]
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.inspectImage(DefaultDockerClient.java:1509) ~[docker-client-8.16.0.jar!/:8.16.0]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.docker.DockerEngineBackend.isImagePresent(DockerEngineBackend.java:243) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.backend.docker.DockerEngineBackend.startContainer(DockerEngineBackend.java:81) ~[containerproxy-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2710) ~[docker-client-8.16.0.jar!/:8.16.0]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:488) ~[jersey-apache-connector-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run(ApacheConnector.java:498) ~[jersey-apache-connector-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:299) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) ~[na:na]
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37) ~[jersey-guava-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:494) ~[jersey-apache-connector-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run(ClientRuntime.java:181) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:303) ~[jersey-common-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run(ClientRuntime.java:209) ~[jersey-client-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:442) ~[jersey-apache-connector-2.26-b03.jar!/:na]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar!/:4.5.13]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are issues related to Docker connectivity in your setup. The key error messages are:

```
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
```

This indicates that ShinyProxy is unable to connect to Docker on your system. Here are a few things you can check and address:

1. Docker Daemon Running:
   Ensure that the Docker daemon is running on your machine. ShinyProxy needs to communicate with Docker to launch containers.
2. Docker Host Configuration:
   ShinyProxy is trying to connect to Docker on localhost:2375. Make sure Docker is configured to accept remote connections. If you are running Docker locally, you might need to expose the Docker daemon as a TCP service. You can do this by modifying the Docker daemon configuration (usually located at `/etc/docker/daemon.json`) to include:

```
{
  "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

After modifying the Docker daemon configuration, restart the Docker daemon.

3. Docker Socket Permissions:

Ensure that the user running ShinyProxy has the necessary permissions to access the Docker socket. You may need to add the user to the `docker` group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

After making this change, you might need to log out and log back in or restart your system for the changes to take effect.

4. Check Docker Connectivity:

Verify that Docker is running and accessible by executing the following command in your terminal:

```
docker info
```

If this command fails, it could indicate an issue with Docker itself.

5. Firewall Settings:

Ensure that there are no firewall rules blocking the communication between ShinyProxy and Docker.

Comment: Sorry I didn't state it well, my OS is win10LTSC2021. Is starting Docker Desktop equivalent to starting Docker.

Comment: Note that the Docker daemon settings described here are incredibly dangerous; enabling an unencrypted network Docker listener is a good way to get your machine compromised.